# How to get the whole block of data using reactjs?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I've created a component which displays only `block[0]` value, it is not showing the whole block value.

For Example, if I write :

```
HI

Stackoverflow
```

It is showing only `"Hi"`, It's not showing the full content of the field.

Can anyone help me in getting the whole data whatever I write in that input field?

```
import React from "react";
import { Editor } from "react-draft-wysiwyg";
import "react-draft-wysiwyg/dist/react-draft-wysiwyg.css";
export default class Edit extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Editor value={this.props.value} onChange={this.props.onChange} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

App component:

```
import React from "react";
import Body from "./Body";
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      body: ""
    };
  }
  changeBodyHandler = value => {
    console.log(value.blocks[0].text);
    this.setState({
      body: value.blocks[0].text
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Body
          label="Body"
          name="body"
          value={this.state.body}
          onChange={this.changeBodyHandler}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Here is the whole code:

"https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-tereshkova-89fm2"

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Which input field meet your problem? `Form.input` or `Editor` ?

Comment: in `changeBodyHandler` what is the result when you do `console.log(value.block.map(item => item.text))`?

Comment: @keikai - It's Editor

Comment: @Sandhya Then you may want to ask the question with the title include `react-draft-wysiwyg`, as well as providing the [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which may reduce misunderstanding, and let others catch your problem quickly.

Comment: @keikai - Nope, i didn't mean in that way, i'm using Editor for the email body purpose but the changeBodyHandler event is taking only one value for the whole block. that is my query. I doon't have any problem with `react-draft-wysiwyg`. I have a problem in displaying the whole message of the body of the email

Comment: @keikai - Could you please see the updated code and assist me in this?

Comment: @Sandhya this is bcos you are getting array of object in block when you enter and start new line in editor. You need to handle all index for getting whole data. but you are accessing only 0th index which has first line data "Hi" in your case. and "Stackoverflow" text is availbale at 1st index of block array

Comment: @heisenberg - Ya, i could figure it out, but i want the whole block of data, i mean if i type `hi` and in the next line if i type `how are you` then i want the whole data to get displayed. Is it possible to get the whole data?

Comment: @heisenberg - Yes i'm accessing block[0] for the first line. For accessing the whole block, Do i need to write looping? I couldn't able to figure it out what type of logic do i need to write there?

Comment: DO you want data in same line or as is it like editor with break

Comment: @heisenberg - I want in a paragraph way, i mean how user types the data, the same way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each line to list, then `map()`, `join()` with `\n` would be fine

```
this.setState({ body: value.blocks.map(x => x.text).join("\n") });
```

```
import React from "react";
import Body from "./Body";
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      body: ""
    };
  }
  changeBodyHandler = value => {
    this.setState({ body: value.blocks.map(x => x.text).join("\n") });
  };
  render() {
    console.log(this.state.body);
    return (
      <div>
        <Body
          label="Body"
          name="body"
          value={this.state.body}
          onChange={this.changeBodyHandler}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

---

[image]

Try it online:

[image: Edit awesome-hamilton-l3h7k]

Answer (score 0):

- If you want with break line like as it is in editor, add `<p>` tag while concatination.

  ```
   changeBodyHandler = value => {
    let data =value.block;
    let text = "";

    data.map(index => {
    text = text +"<p>" +index.text+"</p>";
   });
    this.setState({
      body: text
    });
   };
  ```
- And if you want to display the data in same way somewher use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`

  ```
   <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.state.body}} />
  ```